# Is there any solution to change the color of icon of tab navigation when it's active using react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have problem regarding on the **activeTintColor** the docs of [reactnavigation.org](http://reactnavigation.org) that activeTintColor use for Label and icon color of the active tab. however when i tried to my application only the text is changing the color of the icon still on black.? I will show you guys my codes that I already created

**I will give one example screen of dashboard:**

```
    DriverDashScreen: {
    screen:DriverDashScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel:"Home",
      header: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon type="FontAwesome5" active  name="compass" color={tintColor} style={{fontSize: 18}}/>
      ),
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#2C73D2',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        showIcon: true,
        labelStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

On the screen only the text is changing to **blue color**, but the icon remain **black color**

I hope some one could help me to find what is the problem thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// change screenA and screenB with your routes. 

navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarLabel: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        return <Text style={[styles.tabBar, {color: tintColor}]}>{routeName}</Text>
    },
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        if (routeName === 'screenA') {
            return <Fa5Icons name='compass' size={20} color={tintColor} />
        } else if (routeName === 'screenB') {
            // ...
        }
    },
})
```

`Fa5Icons` imported by:

```
import Fa5Icons from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'
```

Comment: tabBarIcon: unexpected token, please update your post

Comment: Everything is correct, bro. Where's an unexpected token?

Comment: tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {

Comment: What's your routename? you can `console.log(routeName)` or `alert(routeName)` in tabBarIcon.

Comment: my route name is this DriverDashScreen

Comment: Ok. please check my updated answer and use your icon like `<Fa5Icons />`

Comment: bro, how to put the Tab title on the icon? because you remove on it

Comment: Tab label or tab title?

Comment: sorry for that, i want my own label? not my Route name

Comment: bro is it possible to change the tintColor  what i mean is to customize the color of tint?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is `activeTintColor` option in `tabBarOptions`

[reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#bottomtabnavigatorconfig)